# How to count post type that has a particular term?

Tags: wp-query, query

What is the best method to count the number of posts in a post type that have a particular term? I don't believe `get_posts` accepts a term query and I have had no luck with `new WP_Query`, though I might be doing something wrong.

Usage example:

```
$posts = get_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'inventory',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'status',
        'terms' => 'in-stock',
        'field' => 'slug'
    ),
) );
$count =  count( $posts );
echo $count;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$items = get_posts( array(
    'post_type'   => 'inventory',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'taxonomy'    => 'status',
    'term'        => 'in-stock'
    ) );

$count =  count( $items );
echo $count;
```

Comment: that returns an array when echo'd and print_r dumps all the post data, without a count. Was definitely missing the tax_query though, thank you!

Comment: You just need to add that part back in like you had in the original. I edited answer to reflect this.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I had left `$count =  count( $posts ); echo $count;` in as well. Changing the `status` taxonomy term (tried three different terms) does not change the post count. So I'm assuming, unless you have an option to the contrary, that tax_query isn't passing the term. :/

Comment: just updated again. There should be no need to use the taxonomy query if you only need to access one term of one taxonomy.